# Combine two dictionaries and replace keys with values in powershell

Tags: powershell, merge, hashtable

i have two arrays that look like this:

```
$ht1 = @{

"computer55" = "port33"

“computer1” = “port1”

“computer2” = “port2”



}
```

and

```
$ht2 = @{

"A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6" = "port1"

"A2:B3:C4:D5:E6:F7" = "port2"

"A3:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8" = "port33"

"A4:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8" = "port45"
}
```

The first one is one I manually hardcode into the script, I have an actual list of device names and what port they are plugged into on a switch. The second one is generated with a switch script that logs in, gets the mac address table and records it as a hashtable.

My desired outcome is this, if there is a port with an assigned name, replace the port name with the device name.

```
$ht3(or any name) = @{

"A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6" = "computer1"

"A2:B3:C4:D5:E6:F7" = "computer2"

"A3:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8" = "computer55"

"A4:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8" = "port45"
}
```

I've somehow spent about a day on this(... pretty much the first powershell script I've ever came up with) and my end result is always the same, I end up merging two hashtables and pair the port with the computer name and not the mac address with the computer name. any direction is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important note, the `.ContainsValue` method is case sensitive, if you want a case insensitive search use one of the following:

```
if($val = [string]$ht1.Keys.Where({$ht1[$_] -eq $ht2[$key]}))
{
    @{$key = $val}
    continue
}
```

```
if($ht1.Values -contains $ht2[$key])
{
    ...
}
```

```
if($ht2[$key] -in $ht1.Values)
{
   ...
}
```

**Code**

```
$ht1 = @{
    computer55 = 'port33'
    computer1 = 'port1'
    computer2 = 'port2'
}

$ht2 = @{
    'A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6' = 'port1'
    'A2:B3:C4:D5:E6:F7' = 'port2'
    'A3:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8' = 'port33'
    'A4:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8' = 'port45'
}

$result = foreach($key in $ht2.Keys)
{
    if($ht1.ContainsValue($ht2[$key]))
    {
        @{$key = [string]$ht1.Keys.Where({$ht1[$_] -eq $ht2[$key]})}
        continue
    }
    @{$key = $ht2[$key]}
}
```

Looking at `$result` yields:

```
Name                           Value      
----                           -----      
A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6              computer1  
A3:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8              computer55 
A4:B4:C5:D6:E7:F8              port45     
A2:B3:C4:D5:E6:F7              computer2
```

---

```
[string]$ht1.Keys.Where({$ht1[$_] -eq $ht2[$key]})
```

Could also be the following, though, I'm not sure which one would be more efficient:

```
$ht1.GetEnumerator().Where({$_.Value -eq $ht2[$key]}).Key
```

Comment: man, what a simple solution for something i spent a really long time on. thanks.

Comment: @jsss happy to help, this is a fun exercise :)